# javascript is adding key value binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ember.js, handlebars.js

I need to inject via javascript into my code something like this

```
<label {{bindAttr for="view.textField.one"}} >Some label</label>
```

The problem is that jquery/javascript is adding `=""` everywhere and i get

```
<label {{bindAttr="" for="view.textField.one"}}="" >Some label</label>
```

how can I avoid that ?

Comment: Are you using some sort of client-side templating? That may not be the prescribed way to do dynamic bindings.

Comment: When does the `=""` get added?

Comment: @KevinBoucher yes i'm using client-side templating but it should work.

Comment: @ExplosionPills everytime when I get value, replace or inject it to code

Comment: You can't inject handlebars like that, you need to compile it first using http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.html#method_compile and then use it in a view.